# Prevent content creation/edition with rules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-rules

Is it possible to avoid content creation/edition just based in rules?

For example, a rule "before node save" that redirects to home page or other page.

Does this prevent node saving or it just saves and then redirect? if it does prevent, is it *hackeable* like faking a form that submits to the real saving url?

Comment: can't you do this with permissions ?

Comment: I was forced to give extra permissions to anonimous user to solve an issue with a view content, after 2 weeks searching and asking I didn't find other solution than give these permissions

Comment: Unfortunately, even Rules cannot do this in this way. "before node save" means "presave" operation in a hook_nodeapi that means validation and some of the operations are already done. 
To prevent it from saving, you can follow what the Reda's answer says, or make you own hook_nodeapi function to validate form before submission. 
If you can reveal a little more about your use case, i think other users here at SO would answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the node permissions and customize them to override the default values set in `admin/people/permissions` using [hook_node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7)()

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Rules Forms module - https://drupal.org/project/rules_forms - help?